# Cauchy integral problem

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

Cauchy's integral formula states that if $f$ is holomorphic inside and on a positively contour $\gamma$, then if $a$ is inside $\gamma$ we have:
$$ \tag{1}
f(a)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(w)}{w-a} d w
$$
Consider $\gamma=\gamma(0 ; 2)$ and
$$\tag{2}
\int_{\gamma} \frac{\sin z}{z^{2}+1} \mathrm{~d} z
$$
We can rewrite this integral as
$$\tag{3}
\int_{\gamma} \frac{\sin z}{(z+i)(z-i)} d z
$$
and identify $f(z)=\frac{\sin{z}}{1+i}, a=i$. We then get using eq. $(1)$
$$\tag{4}
\int_{\gamma} \frac{\sin z}{z^{2}+1} \mathrm{~d} z=2\pi i\cdot\frac{\sin{i}}{2i}=i\pi \sinh{1}
$$
However, if I do the integral in Mathematica I get a result of $2\pi i \sinh{1}$, i.e., a factor of $2$ larger. Did I make a mistake when using the integral formula?

Comment: there are two residues inside so one has to add them as $z=-i$ is a pole too (hence your $f$ is not holomorphic btw and one has to use the general residue theorem or simple fractions)

Comment: Thank you. I have not gotten to the residue theorem in my course yet.

Comment: then simple fractions is the way to go so write $ \frac{\sin z}{z^{2}+1}=(\frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{1}{z+i})\frac{\sin z}{2i}$ and apply Cauchy to each term etc

Comment: Great, thank you!